# Laravel migration ErrorException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Thanks for reading.

I've created a new Laravel project using composer `composer create-project laravel/laravel name`
And when I try to `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

```
  ErrorException

  Illegal offset type in isset or empty

  at C:\Users\pc\Desktop\xyz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1159
    1155|      * @return string
    1156|      */
    1157|     public function getAlias($abstract)
    1158|     {
  > 1159|         if (! isset($this->aliases[$abstract])) {
    1160|             return $abstract;
    1161|         }
    1162|
    1163|
```

I haven't changed nothing since creating the project with composer.

Comment: I suggest editing the question with the version of Laravel installed and how did you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the following commands in terminal

```
copy .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

then in .env file enter your Database credential

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Hopefully, it will be worked for you

Comment: Thanks for the help but doing these haven't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in version 7.16.1

Run `php artisan --version`

Do an update with `composer update`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33234#issue-639781041